# Modsecurity block access from all countries except from a specific IP or specific remote host

Tags: security, apache-2.4, apache2, mod-security

I have the below 3 rules in `modsecurity`.

**Rule 1**: Block all countries defined as high risk except `US`:

```
SecAction \
 "id:900600,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:'tx.high_risk_country_codes = AD AE AF AG AI AL AM AO AQ AR...'"

#Allow only the below countries
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@geoLookup" "chain,id:2000001,drop,msg:'Countries allowed'"
SecRule GEO:COUNTRY_CODE "!@pm US"
```

**Rule 2**: Allow access from the following IP:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^XX\.XX\.XX\.XX$" "phase:1,id:2000002,nolog,allow,msg:'Allow access from IP XX.XX.XX.XX'"
```

**Rule 3**: Allow access from the following remote host:

```
SecRule REMOTE_HOST "host\.name\.com$" "phase:1,id:2000003,nolog,allow,msg:'Allow access from host.name.com'"
```

All rules work well if we take any one of them. However, I'd like to "merge" them into one rule which does the following:

Block all access from the forbidden countries (Rule 1), except when the request comes from IP `XX.XX.XX.XX` (Rule 2) or except when the host is `host.name.com` (Rule 3).

How can I do that in modscurity?

Comment: Do not cross site post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103795/modsecurity-block-access-from-all-countries-except-from-a-specific-ip-or-specifi